# Weird WLAN connection

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection

I assembled my first computer on my own. As I realised it had no WLAN (AsRock Z77 Extreme 4m) I bought a WLAN stick (ZyXel NWD 2105), plugged it in, started the setup from the CD and it worked, until I restarted the PC. That's when the problems started. The stick is able to connect to the router (P-660HN-F1Z) and the connection is stable, but not the internet access. In estimately 1 minute intervals there might be a short connection timeframe and dropbox or windows update are able to download some data, but as soon as I try to open a website the internet access is away. Note that the connection to the router does not shut down and remains stable at around 80-90%. The problem is definetly located on my pc, because with my laptop and phone the connection is stable and fast.

Because I was so mad, I bought a EW-7612PIn V2 (PCI-E WLAN adapter), same problem.

Now the weird thing is, if I don't use the PC for about 2 days, start it up, there is internet access (happened with both the stick and the PCI-E card). A bit slow, but it does not get away just like that, until I shut it down. Then, no matter how many times I restart, it won't come back. I googled a lot but now I'm at the end with my latin. Has anyone had a similar problem and resolved it?

Technical details:
Motherboard: AsRock Z77 Extreme 4M
OS: Windows 7 professional 64bit
Stick: Zyxel wireless N adapter NWD2105
PCI-E card: Edimax EW-7612PIn V2
Router: ZyXel P-660HN-F1Z

```
 Windows-IP-Konfiguration

   Hostname  . . . . . . . . . . . . : xyz
   Primäres DNS-Suffix . . . . . . . :
   Knotentyp . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP-Routing aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein
   WINS-Proxy aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter Drahtlosnetzwerkverbindung 5:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #
3
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 80-1F-02-61-C0-A6
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Drahtlos-LAN-Adapter Drahtlosnetzwerkverbindung 4:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Edimax 802.11n Wireless Adapter
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 80-1F-02-61-C0-A6
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::38d2:f489:726d:1fb5%17(Bevorzugt)
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.41(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease erhalten. . . . . . . . . . : Donnerstag, 15. November 2012 10:51:05
   Lease läuft ab. . . . . . . . . . : Sonntag, 18. November 2012 10:51:18
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 578821890
   DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-FF-D5-FE-BC-5F-F4-48-FC-4B

   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 91.233.182.2
                                       194.230.1.39
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert

Tunneladapter isatap.{263BEB98-344B-435C-888F-1B15B97C3AC1}:

   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja

Tunneladapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:209c:2944:3f57:fed6(Bevo
rzugt)
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::209c:2944:3f57:fed6%11(Bevorzugt)
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Deaktiviert


C:\Users\xyz>ping 192.168.1.1

Ping wird ausgeführt für 192.168.1.1 mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Antwort von 192.168.1.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=2ms TTL=254
Antwort von 192.168.1.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=2ms TTL=254
Antwort von 192.168.1.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=2ms TTL=254
Antwort von 192.168.1.1: Bytes=32 Zeit=2ms TTL=254

Ping-Statistik für 192.168.1.1:
    Pakete: Gesendet = 4, Empfangen = 4, Verloren = 0
    (0% Verlust),
Ca. Zeitangaben in Millisek.:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 2ms, Mittelwert = 2ms
```

Comment: Run in Windows `cmd.exe` and use command `ipconfig /all`, post everything regarding your wireless adapter. After that, copy IP address of gateway from previous command and run with `ping gatewayipaddress`, post results also.

Comment: is it because of the hybrid in Knotentyp? My laptop shows peer-to-peer if I do the same there.

Comment: Knotentyp (aka NodeType) is just a way netbios is work, that's just for windows pc hostname resolution in your LAN, that's not the case here. Maybe It could be your dns settings, you may try to add `8.8.8.8` (google dns) as your primary dns server. May also disable `ipv6` just to clear things up, if you don't need it ofcourse. Is internet working with that settings you posted, mean right now?

Comment: with the settings posted, dropbox is able to upload files (very slow), but I'm not able to open any website. Also sometimes spotify is able to connect and show the news page etc. but I cannot play any song.

Comment: the dns is now 8.8.8.8 and ipv6 is off, no change. Is it possible that just one port is open and therefore just one application at one time has access or something in this direction?

Comment: Ok, if that dns setting won't work, I would try to connect via Ethernet, directly to router, if it's possible. Shut down wifi and try to connect. Or you may try turn off `N-mode` on wifi adapter, try to connect via `G` type connection.

Comment: Sadly it is no possible to connect via ethernet, I would have to make a hole in the floor, this is why I'm slowly climbing the walls. Setting the router to g or n mode only didn't help either. But thank you a lot for your support so far.

Comment: I found one interesting thing. In the router config page there is a log and it shows that my ip is exceeding the max. number of sessions per host. And one other error is Exceed MAX incomplete, sent TCP RST: TCP

Comment: You can run in `cmd.exe` with administrator rights, `netstat -a -n -b` to see all active connections from your pc with id of programs that are using it. See also in task manager how much bandwidth is used by wifi adapter.

Comment: If that won't show any suspicious traffic going on. Look at this http://www.dslreports.com/forum/remark,15504919 it could be your problem. Upon that discussion I would try to set your IP address manually, if this wont help try disable dhcp server on router, restart router and try your PC connectivity again.

Comment: Did you try to disable DHCP ?

Comment: This question is four years old, I'm no longer in this situation so it is kind of resolved.